# How do I load data that has a Many to Many relationship in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, many-to-many, fluent

I'm working on a many to many relationship in my ASP.NET Core application.  From reading sources online I understand that this isn't officially supported yet and so an intermediary class is needed to make it all work.

The problem that I have is that once I have created my 'many to many' relationship, I don't know how best to display the data in my view and I'm struggling to traverse everything with this particular setup.

In my example there are two tables `Part` and `Supplier`, one `Part` can have many `Supplier` just as one `Supplier` can have many `Part`.

The first thing I did was create my two entity classes `Part` and `Supplier`

***Part.cs***

```
public class Part
{
    public int PartId { get; set; }
    public string PartName { get; set; }
    public string PartNumber { get; set; }
    public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
    public string LongDescription { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }

    //Intermediate entity
    public IList<PartSupplier> PartSupplier { get; set; }
}
```

***Supplier.cs***

```
public class Supplier
{
    public int SupplierId { get; set; }
    public string SupplierName { get; set; }
    public string Website { get; set; }
    public int? Telephone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    //Intermediate entity
    public IList<PartSupplier> PartSupplier { get; set; }        
}
```

You'll see from the above code that I've placed an intermediate table that creates this many to many relationship called `PartSupplier`

***PartSupplier.cs***

```
public class PartSupplier
{
    public int PartId { get; set; }
    public Part Part { get; set; }

    public int SupplierId { get; set; }
    public Supplier Supplier { get; set; }
}
```

At this point, I move to my data context and override the model building portion of the code to utilise the Fluent API.

***Context.cs***

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{            
    builder.Entity<PartSupplier>().HasKey(ps => new { ps.PartId, ps.SupplierId });
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);
}
public DbSet<Part> Parts { get; set; }
public DbSet<Supplier> Suppliers { get; set; }
public DbSet<PartSupplier> PartSuppliers { get; set; }
```

Ok, so far so good.  Now I need to display this information in a view, in this view specifically, I'd like to show all the parts and next to them all the available suppliers that part can be bought from.

I load the data in the following manner although, this is where I'm a little unsure how I should be structuring the query.  Should I call the intermediary table or call `Part` and then include `Supplier`?  I'm not sure

***PartController.cs***

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var data = _context.Part.Include(p => p.Supplier);
    return View(data);
}
```

***Index.cshtml***

```
@model IEnumerable<Part>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <h2>Parts</h2>
            <a asp-action="Create" asp-controller="Parts">Add Part</a>
            <table class="table">
                @foreach (var part in Model)
                {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@part.PartId" asp-controller="Part">@part.PartName</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @part.PartNumber
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @part.ShortDescription
                    </td>
                    <td>
                       ...I'd like to show the suppliers here...
                    </td>
                </tr>
                }
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I think I've almost got it but really would like some assistance getting over this final hurdle.  Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

A cascade relationship is missing in `Index.cshtml`, you need to add `ThenInclude`.

```
public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var data = _context.Parts.Include(x => x.PartSupplier)
            .ThenInclude(y=>y.Supplier);
        return View(data);
    }
```

Then in Index.cshtml.

```
<table class="table">
            @foreach (var part in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@part.PartId" asp-controller="Part">@part.PartName</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @part.PartNumber
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @part.ShortDescription
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <ul>
                   @* Here has been changed. *@
                            @foreach(var supplier in part.PartSupplier)
                            {
                                <li>@supplier.Supplier.SupplierName @supplier.Supplier.Website</li>
                            }
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
```

In database, I insert some data, such as `Part` and `PartSupplier`.

[image]
[image]

Result.

[image]